What is this transformer doing next to this piezo buzzer?
I'm looking at a few schematics that share the a similar circuit for the Piezo buzzer. The way that this buzzer is being driven is interesting to me. What I think is happening is that the MCU is sending out a square wave into the transistor, driving the piezo buzzer. From there, a transformer is being used with the buzzer to create an LC tank circuit, so when the transistor is turning ON and OFF, the audio is modulated to reflect the voltage oscillating waveform on the tank circuit. This is what I think is happening, but I'm not completely sure.
I'm posting here since I wanted to ask the following:

Is my understanding on how these circuits work correct? If not, what am I misunderstanding?

Why do you think a center tap transformer was used for circuit A, and a normal transformer was used for circuit B?

Is back EMF a concern for this circuit, since there is an inductive element?

Could a normal inductor be used in place of a transformer?


Circuit A

Circuit B



Your underatanding could be correct or not. The MCU cannot sense the resonance so it might not be driven as LC resonance tank but simply some forced frequency set by the MCU. The piezo may be driven with simple continuous wave of some frequency, instead of being modulated with audio like PWM. We don't know what the circuits are intended for.

The center tapped transformer is used to drive both legs of the piezo with 6.6Vpp AC signal. It doubles the amplitude of the transistor driving only 3.3 Vpp AC signal into one piezo leg. The transformer is used to drive both piezo legs with some higher AC amplitude signal dependent on winding ratio. Both signals remove DC from the piezo drive signal, as they must not have a DC bias between piezo terminals.

It could be a problem or maybe not, it depends on the transformer inductance, turns ratios, and piezo capacitance. Without further information on each component, it can't be analyzed.

Maybe, but then you have to change the circuit to work with it. The piezo cannot tolerate DC bias, so it would depend on which kind of circuit you suggest if it can be used or not.


